# Как сделать рекурсивный реверс строки?

Tags: javascript, задание-на-собеседовании

Решаю задачи, которые задают на собеседовании.

> **Требуется** : написать рекурсивную функцию, которая переворачивает строку.

Самостоятельно решил двумя отличными друг от друга способами, но какой из них предпочтительней и почему без Вашей помощи определить не смогу.

И был бы рад увидеть более оптимальные варианты.

I способ :

```js
function repl_str(str) {
  if (typeof str == "string")
    str = {
      str: str,
      index: 0,
      buff: ""
    };
  else if (str.index >= str.str.length) return str.buff;

  str.buff += str.str.substring(str.str.length - (str.index + 1), str.str.length - str.index);
  str.index++;

  return repl_str(str);
}
console.log(repl_str("test")); //tset
```

II способ :

```js
function repl_str(str, stack) {
  if (typeof stack == "undefined") {
    stack = {};
    stack.index = 0;
    stack.buff = "";
  } else if (stack.index >= str.length) return stack.buff;

  stack.buff += str.substring(str.length - (stack.index + 1), str.length - stack.index);
  stack.index++;
  return repl_str(str, stack);
}

console.log(repl_str("test")); //tset
```

Comment: Пишете тесты, проверяете обе функции на правильность поведения.
Пишете ещё тесты и проверяете обе функции на скорость.
Ваш результат.

Comment: а можно поинтересоваться откуда это задание? Просто Вас попросили завязать галстук на шее через .... Да, при помощи рекурсии можно сделать все что угодно, но это не означает что опытный программист, который постоянно имеет дело с рекурсией, сможет с полпинка сделать реверс строки. В жизни рекурсию так не применяют и поэтому мозг не может понять что его просят. А плохого в коде то, что в некоторый момент аргументы меняют свой тип со стринка на обжект, а так же сомнительно использовать substring. И ещё нужно было уточнить, какие параметры допустимы, а то в идеале всегда должна быть строка.

Comment: И ещё нужно было спросить о внутренностях рекурсивной функции, что именно там можно использовать. Рекурсии нет даже в самых лучших фраймворках, потому что она не нежна, она медленная. Её используют только при обходе деревьев..

Comment: Имхо, такая задача элементарно делается через Array.prototype.reverse();

http://jsfiddle.net/IonDen/a4p8yceh/

    var test = "Very long text";
    function reverse (str) {
        var temp = str.split('');
        temp.reverse();
        return temp.join('');
    }
    reverse(test)

Answer (score 10):

как-то так наверное хотелось

```
function r(a) {
 return a === '' ? '' : r(a.slice(1)) + a[0];
}
```

без slice:

```
function r(a,n) {
 n = typeof n === 'undefined' ? a.length - 1 : n - 1;
 return n >= 0 ? a[n] + r(a, n) : '';
}
```

но последняя какая-то глупая рекурсия.

для slice варианта придумал "оптимизацию" (-1 вызов)

```
function r(a) {
  return a.length - 1 ? r(a.slice(1)) + a[0] : a;
};
```

ES6:

```
const r = (a) => a.length - 1 ? r(a.slice(1)) + a[0] : a;
```

подсмотрел такой хак для рекурсии на стрелочных функциях

```
(
  (
    a,
    r = (a) => a.length-1 ? r(a.slice(1)) + a[0] : a // дефолтный параметр r
  ) => r(a)
)("abcdef");
```

чет я тогда забыл про reverse: :)

```
"12345".split('').reverse().join('');
```

Comment: Первая просто круть!

Answer (score 4):

Можно так например.

```
function r(s){return s.length == 0 ? s : r(s.substring(1)).concat(s.charAt(0));}
```

**UPD**: Отрефакторил в однострочник.

Раскрытие рекурсии:

```
r("Лезу в узеЛ")
(r("Лезу в узе")) + "Л"
((r("Лезу в уз")) + "е") + "Л"
(((r("Лезу в у")) + "з") + "e") + "Л"
((((r("Лезу в ")) + "у") + "з") + "e") + "Л"
(((((r("Лезу в")) + " ") + "у") + "з") + "e") + "Л"
((((((r("Лезу ")) + "в") + " ") + "у") + "з") + "e") + "Л"
(((((((r("Лезу")) + " ") + "в") + " ") + "у") + "з") + "e") + "Л"
((((((((r("Лез")) + "у") + " ") + "в") + " ") + "у") + "з") + "e") + "Л"
(((((((((r("Ле")) + "з") + "у") + " ") + "в") + " ") + "у") + "з") + "e") + "Л"
((((((((((r("Л")) + "e") + "з") + "у") + " ") + "в") + " ") + "у") + "з") + "e") + "Л"
```

А вот собственно симметричный вариант, говорят что он в два раза медленее асимметричного:

```
function r(s) {
  if (s.length < 2)
    return s;
  var halfIndex = Math.ceil(s.length / 2);
  return r(s.substr(halfIndex)) + r(s.substr(0, halfIndex));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

А почему ещё никто не предложил хвостовую рекурсию? Хей, js же функциональный язык!

```
function r(s) {
    function r1(s, tail) {
        return s === '' ? tail : r1(s.substring(1), s[0] + tail);
    }
    return r1(s, '');
}
```

```js
function r(s) {
    function r1(s, tail) {
        return s === '' ? tail : r1(s.substring(1), s[0] + tail);
    }
    return r1(s, '');
}

function doit() {
    $('#r').text( r ($('#i').val()) );
}
$(':button').click(doit);
doit();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="i" value="string example">
<br>
<button type="button">reverse!</button>
<br>
Result: <div id="r">
```

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант -

```
function reverce(string) {
    var length = string.length == 1 ? 0 : string.length;
    var result = '';

    while (length--) {
        result += reverce(string[length]);

        if (length == 0) {
            string = result;
        }
    }

    return string;
}
```

И тест -

```js
'use strict';

const REPEAT = 5;
const ITERATION = 100000;

var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

function getP(){
 return document.createElement('p');
}


function runTest(callback){
 var repeat = REPEAT;

 while(repeat-- > 0)
 {
  var result = speed(callback);
  var p = getP();
  p.innerHTML = result;
  body.appendChild(p);

  console.log(result);
 }
}


function speed(callback){

 var startTime = new Date();
 for (var z = 0; z < ITERATION; z++) {
  callback();
 }

 var finishTime = new Date();
 return 'Время выполнения - ' + (finishTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime()) + '.' 
}

// runTest();

console.log('===== start =====');

var p = getP();
p.innerHTML = '### TEST - 1';

body.appendChild(p);

runTest(one);

function one(){

 repl_str('some text');

 function repl_str(str)
 {
     if (typeof str == "string")
         str = { str: str, index: 0, buff: "" };
     else if (str.index >= str.str.length) return str.buff;

     str.buff += str.str.substring(str.str.length - (str.index + 1), str.str.length - str.index);
     str.index++;

     return repl_str(str);
 }
}

console.log('===== start =====');

var p = getP();
p.innerHTML = '### TEST - 2';

body.appendChild(p);
runTest(two);

function two(){

 repl_str('some text');

 function repl_str(str, stack)
 {
     if (typeof stack == "undefined")
     {
         stack = {};
         stack.index = 0;
         stack.buff = "";
     } else if (stack.index >= str.length) return stack.buff;

     stack.buff += str.substring(str.length - (stack.index + 1), str.length - stack.index);
     stack.index++;
     return repl_str(str, stack);
 }
}

console.log('===== start =====');

var p = getP();
p.innerHTML = '### TEST - 3';

body.appendChild(p);
runTest(three);

function three(){

 reverce('some text');

 function reverce(string) {
      var length = string.length == 1 ? 0 : string.length;
      var result = '';
 
      while (length--) {
          result += reverce(string[length]);
 
          if (length == 0) {
              string = result;
          }
      }
 
      return string;
  };
}
console.log('=================');
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
const reverse = a => a.length === 0 
? [] 
: [ a[a.length - 1], ...reverse(a.slice(0, a.length - 1)) ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Наглядный вариант, итеративный процесс.

```
const revers = (str) => {
  const lastIndex = str.length - 1;

    const iter = (i, acc) => {
      if(i > lastIndex) return acc;
      return iter(i + 1, `${str[i]}${acc}`)
    }

  return iter(0, '');
};
```

Answer (score -1):

**Ну или например**

```
const reverse = (str) => {
    let result = '';
    for (let i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        result += str[i];
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Тут есть рекурсия?